# How to create datediff calculation in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

Is there a way I can use Datediff in Power Query as a calculated column?

This is the calculation I would like to do:

`datediff("minute",[Login Time],[Logout Time])`

The login time and logout time columns look like this:

[image]

I would greatly appreciate your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Duration functions.  First create the direction:

```
Duration.From([EndDate] - [StartDate])
```

Then you can use Duration.TotalMinutes(*Durationvalue*)

Comment: I think you may want to use `Duration.From` and not `Duration.Days`.  `Duration.Days` will return a `number`, but the argument for `Duration.TotalMinutes` needs to be a `duration`.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You are right.  Got caught doing it by memory.